# Returning an Answer using VBA in a TextBox

Tags: vba, excel, userform, calculated-field

I am creating a fairly simple userform. The user has to enter 2 values that I want to calculate and enter into a column on my spreadsheet in Excel.

I am not sure how to format the VBA to have it calculate these values and then save it in the spreadsheet.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub txtRecruitPct_Change()
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer

    A = txtApprovedAffs.Value
    B = txtEmailsSent.Value

    Answer = A / B    
End Sub
```

I need to know how to get this value to calculate and save in the specific column in Excel.

Comment: Well you would need to check and make sure the user is entering numbers.  Where is your code for your userform?

Comment: Then you would need to have the destination cell `Range("Cell Address").Value = Answer`

Comment: You're asking for the syntax to write `Range("A1").Value = A`, `Range("A2").Value = B` and `Range("A3").Value = Answer`, said your column is `A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to dump all your answers into column "A" then:

```
Private Sub txtRecruitPct_Change()
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long

    A = txtApprovedAffs.Value
    B = txtEmailsSent.Value

    Answer = A / B
    LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G" & LastRow + 1).Value = Answer

End Sub
```

If you wanted all the data in seperate columns:

```
Private Sub txtRecruitPct_Change()
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim B As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long

    A = txtApprovedAffs.Value
    B = txtEmailsSent.Value

    Answer = A / B
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = A
    Range("B" & LastRow + 1).Value = B
    Range("C" & LastRow + 1).Value = Answer

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this...so if I were say adding this to column G I would change it to LastRow = Range ("A"& Rows.Count).End(xlUP).Row Range ("A" & LastRow+6).Value=Answer?

Comment: I will amend my code.  Basically change all the "A" to "G" `LastRow = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Range("G" & LastRow + 1).Value = Answer`